# Remove duplicates from LUA Table by timestamp

Tags: lua, lua-table, deduplication

I was on stack a few days back for help inserting records to prevent duplicates. However the process to enter these is slow and they slip in.

I have a user base of about 10,000 players, and they have duplicate entries.. I've been trying to filter out these duplicates without success. The examples on stack have no panned out for me.

Here is  a clip from my table

```
    [18] = 
                {
                    ["soldAmount"] = 25,
                    ["buyer"] = [[@playername]],
                    ["timestampz"] = 1398004426,
                    ["secsSinceEvent"] = 55051,
                    ["guildName"] = [[TradingGuild]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["seller"] = [[@myname]],
                },
    [19] = 
                {
                    ["soldAmount"] = 25,
                    ["buyer"] = [[@playername]],
                    ["timestampz"] = 1398004426,
                    ["secsSinceEvent"] = 55051,
                    ["guildName"] = [[TradingGuild]],
                    ["eventType"] = 15,
                    ["seller"] = [[@myname]],
                },
```

The timestamp's match and they should not have been added.

```
  for k,v in pairs(sellHistory) do mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[k] = v
    if mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales.timestampz ~= sellHistory.timestampz then
      table.insert(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales, sellHistory)
    end end
```

Now, I need to find out how to remove the current duplicates, and here is what I've tried.

```
function table_unique(tt)
  local newtable = {}
  for ii,xx in ipairs(tt) do
    if table_count(newtable.timestampz, xx) ~= tt.timestampz then
      newtable[#newtable+1] = xx
    end
  end
  return newtable
end
```

I hope this information provided was clean and understandable.

Thanks!

UPDATE

Attempt #20 ;)

```
  for k,v in pairs(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales) do
    if v == mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales.timestampz then
      table.remove(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales,k)
    end
  end
```

No luck yet.

UPDATE

This has worked

```
  for k,v in pairs(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales) do mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[k] = v
    if v.timestampz == mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales.timestampz then
      table.remove(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales, k)
    end
  end
```

IS this a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[18]` and `mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[19]` are the tables you listed in your post, then to remove all duplicates based on same time stamp it is easiest to create a "set" based on timestamp (since the timestamp is your condition for uniqueness). Loop through your `mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales` and for each item, add item to new table only if its timestamp not already in set:

```
function removeDuplicates(tbl)
    local timestamps = {}
    local newTable = {}
    for index, record in ipairs(tbl) do
        if timestamps[record.timestampz] == nil then
            timestamps[record.timestampz] = 1
            table.insert(newTable, record)
        end
    end
    return newTable
end

mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales = removeDuplicates(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales)
```

*Update based on Question Update:*

My comment on following proposed solution:

```
for k,v in pairs(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales) do 
  mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[k] = v
  if v.timestampz == mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales.timestampz then
    table.remove(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales, k)
  end
end
```

The problem is that I don't see how that can work. When you do `for k,v in pairs(mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales) do` then `v` is `mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[k]` so the next line `mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[k] = v` does nothing.  Then `if v.timestampz == mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales.timestampz` compares the timestamp of `v`, i.e. of `mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales[k]`, with value of a `timestampz` field in `mSavedTHVars.Forever_Sales`. But latter is a table without such field, so right-hand-side of `==` will be nil, so the condition will only be true if `v.timestampz` is nil, which I don't think is ever the case.

The main reason that I used a solution of creating new table instead of removing duplicates from the existing table is that you can edit a table while iterating over it with pairs or ipairs. If you were to use a reverse counter, it would probably be ok (but I have not tested, test to be sure):

```
function removeDuplicates(tbl)
    local timestamps = {}
    local numItems = #tbl
    for index=numItems, 1, -1, do
        local record = tbl[index]
        if timestamps[record.timestampz] ~= nil then
            table.remove(newTable, index)
        end
        timestamps[record.timestampz] = 1
    end
end
```

Also I think the intent of the function is not as clear, but maybe this is just personal preference.

Comment: I added an update above, which seems to be working. Does that look like a good approach?

Comment: @WilliamRussell no, I cleaned up my answer because I realized there was no point in trying the first two solutions I discussed, just the last one is best, I hope this is the one you accepted.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to work as well. from this function and my update above what do you think would be the difference (or harm in mine)?  --Edit I plan on using yours... just curious

Comment: @WilliamRussell I extended my answer to discuss your proposed solution and gave alternative that uses remove instead of new table insert.